# Laravel Sanctum and external SPA returning 401 error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

So I've been trying to get my SPA Application to authenticate on my Laravel API.

The SPA is active on admin.app.test, I have another SPA that does not require authorization on app.test. The laravel application is active on app.test/api. So now that you know the infrastructure, lets go to the laravel files.

Kernel.php:

```
'api' => [
  \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
  'throttle:api',
  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
],
```

The sanctum.php and session.php files are both default, as I can configure then within my .env file.

configuration in my .env file :

```
APP_URL=http://app.test

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="admin.app.test"

SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_LIFETIME=180
SESSION_DOMAIN=".app.test"
```

For some reason I am getting a 401 error with `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` on every `auth:sanctum` route

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'getUser']);
});
```

I have read the docs multiple times and made sure everything was working as it is supposed to be. ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with my setup actually had nothing to do with sanctum but with my `web` middleware. See, as I am using laravel as API only I did not have the need for any unused web middleware.

The problem is that sanctum uses `web` for authentication. So I ended up adding the following web middleware:

```
'web' => [
  \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
  \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
  \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
  \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
```

Now I can succesfully authenticate on my vuejs spa and access my protected routes.

Answer (score 0):

You may add Supports Credential by following ways -

1. In `config/cors.php` file - Set

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'supports_credentials' => true,
```

2. If you use VUE then, add edit - `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

3. In `.env`

```
APP_URL=localhost/Project_Name
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost/Project_Name
```